# how to construct a 6 by 6 symmetric matrix of rank 3 in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I want to construct a 6X6 symmetric matrix A of rank 3 in MATLAB. any suggestions?

tried different ways, couldn't end up with expected result

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: There are infinitely many of these matrices, and a lot of ways to build them. You could randomly pick three non zero eigenvalues, build three independent vectors and reverse the diagonalization process for example

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diag`:

```
diag([1,1,1,0,0,0])
```

This will produce a diagonal matrix, where the first three entries are ones, and the rest are zeros. Since it is diagonal it is symmetric. And because only three of the diagonal entries are nonzero, it has rank three.

Answer (score 1):

You can try constructing a 6-by-3 matrix `H` first and using `A = H*H'` in turn to achieve your objective

```
>> H = randn(6,3)

H =

    1.4090    0.4889    0.8884
    1.4172    1.0347   -1.1471
    0.6715    0.7269   -1.0689
   -1.2075   -0.3034   -0.8095
    0.7172    0.2939   -2.9443
    1.6302   -0.7873    1.4384

>> A = H*H'

A =

    3.0136    1.4837    0.3520   -2.5689   -1.4614    3.1900
    1.4837    4.3948    2.9298   -1.0967    4.6978   -0.1542
    0.3520    2.9298    2.1218   -0.1661    3.8423   -1.0150
   -2.5689   -1.0967   -0.1661    2.2054    1.4282   -2.8940
   -1.4614    4.6978    3.8423    1.4282    9.2696   -3.2971
    3.1900   -0.1542   -1.0150   -2.8940   -3.2971    5.3464
```

To verify the resulting `A`

```
>> rank(A)

ans =

     3

>> ishermitian(A)

ans =

  logical

   1
```

Comment: Note that if `H` complex and not real, then `A = H*H'` will produce a hermitian, but not a symmetric matrix. Using `A = H*H.'` will always result in a symmetric matrix though.

Comment: @flawr yes, you are right.